# how to put html tag in label columnheader?

Tags: dojo

I use dgrid to make a simple grid (http://dojofoundation.org/packages/dgrid/tutorials/defining_grid_structures/).
My question is simple : how to put html tag in label columnheader's ? Because if I put an img tag for example, label contains the string img src=...
Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The column definition can provide a function that builds the column header.

```js
var column = {
    //...
    renderHeaderCell: function(node) {
        domConstruct.create('img', {src: ''}, node);
        return node;
    }
};
```

See the documentation of the `renderHeaderCell()` function in the [DGrid wiki](https://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/Grid):

> `renderHeaderCell(node)`
>
> An optional function that will be called to render the column's header
>   cell. Like renderCell, this may either operate on the node directly,
>   or return a node to be placed within it.

Comment: I've tried this solution, but recieve an error saying 'Failed to execute appendChild on 'Node' : The new child element contains the parent' -- do you know what could be causing this?

Answer (score 0):

One-line answer using `put-selector`:

```
renderHeaderCell: function(node) {
    return put("img[src=/your/image]");
}
```

Note this function won't work if your column happens to be a selector - because [selector.js](http://github.com/SitePen/dgrid/wiki/selector) defines his own `renderHeaderCell(node)` function.

Answer (score 0):

@craig Thanks for the answer, in my case I only needed to know how to add HTML into the header cell and the `renderHeaderCell(node)` was definitely the answer.

For anyone else simply needing to add a `<br>`, `<span>`, `<div>` etc to the header cell, here's a couple of simple examples to compare:

**Example without using `renderHeaderCell(node)`:**

```
{
    label: 'Title',
    field: appConfig.fields[0],
    sortable: false
}
```

**Example using `renderHeaderCell(node)`:**

```
{
    renderHeaderCell: function(node) {
        node.innerHTML = '<span class="headerCell">Title<br><br></span>'
    },
    field: appConfig.fields[0],
    sortable: false
}
```

Then you can target with CSS as normal:

```
.headerCell {
    font-size: 9px;
}
```